# way to call multiple variables from a list in R

Tags: r, variables

I have various variables in a list, and what I would like to do is to call them in my code, by using the list. ie:

```
variables <- as.list(c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3",......,"variablen"))
```

What i would like to do is sth like:

```
variables[1] <- c("my text")
```

and have sth like:

```
variable1 <- c("my text")
```

Comment: Do you want to create separate objects for every value of `variables` ? What should be the value in them ?

Comment: What do you mean by "sth"? Even apart from that, this question is on the obscure side. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the function `assign`. The variable name is the first argument, which you can provide programmatically. Something like this:

```
assign(variables[[1]], 'my text')
variable1
```

Output: `'my text'`

---

However using `assign` is generally recommended against. A named list would likely work just as well or perhaps better for you:

```
newlist = c('my text', 'hello', 'world')
names(newlist) = c('variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3')
newlist[['variable1']]
```

Output: `'my text'`

Comment: @joran haha fair